# Why are some objects visible in the outliner but not in the 3D view?

Tags: outliner

[image]

In this scene I have banners on the pillars, it is also selected in the outliner at the moment, but I cant seem to find the banners? I don't know if I hid the object, or what but I cant find them at all anymore? I have tried unhiding everything, but nothing, this really confuses me as it is in the outliner and the texture for it is there.

[image]

Comment: Try Checking other Layers.

Comment: I have checked all the other layers no luck :(

Comment: You can see an orange dot on the 5th layer. This shows the object is on this layer. The 5th layer is not currently selected to be visible, only layers 1 and 11 are.

Comment: Can you post your blend File? https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file

Comment: It is model banner that fits around the pillar. I will post my .blend file on this question as soon as i figure out how to do so

Comment: You can use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload blend files and then [edit] your question to add the embed code.

Comment: I tried this, it seems my file is 16 mb too big, should i upload to dropbox and share the link?

Comment: Reduce your file to the simplest example that still has the issue.

Comment: Ok, I did it, hope it works, im still fairly new to blender stack exchange, To whom ever will open this file, the banner is a rectangle shape around each of the bottom pillars, I also have a set of tv screens on the right side wall that seem to be having the same issue as the banners.

Comment: There's no Banners  I found in the image you posted the selected object Cube.008  is a pillar.

Comment: cube.008 is the banner, the pillar is called Ho26l271, if you toggle its visibility you will see it is the pillar. If it has a texture connected to it called prime 2 then it is the texture that is connected to the banner, which means you have found the banner in the outliner... now its just to get it to show up in the viewport

Comment: I found the TV that you are referencing at on the right wall TV is present in the 5th Layer & all the banners too. With all layer selected I toggled the visibility of cube.008 it shows a pillar behind Just press Console to see all the layers at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, the pillar object is on layer 5 and you only have layers 1 and 11 set to be visible. Showing layer 5 reveals the 'banner' (shown as pink due to missing textures):

[image]

I can see it is on layer 5 because the orange dot appears on the 5th square of the layers UI, indicating the layer the selected object is on:

[image]

You need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> while selecting the 5th layer to make it visible along with the other layers. The squares indicating the layers go a dark colour when they are selected (or in the case of your Blender theme, blue), which is how I could tell only layers 1 and 11 are selected in your original screenshot.

For more information on viewing and managing layers, see the [Layers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/layers.html#viewing-layers) section of the Blender Manual.

Comment: I feel so stupid now, I checked through all my layers individually and i didn't spot them at all, I apologize for this, I do see them now.... Thank you so much for assisting me, and again, i do apologize for my silly mistake.